# Python doesn't compile when executed from the terminal, but compiles when run from atom editor

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm running this code:

```
import os

file_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
print file_path

accel = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../imu/accel.txt')
```

First I ran it from my atom editor using the 'script' package and it outputted:

[image]

But when I ran the same code from the terminal I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "imu_pub2.py", line 9, in <module>
    accel = open(os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../imu/accel.txt')
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/../imu/accel.txt'
```

Why is this happening?

The compile error happens at the last line of the code. For some reason in the terminal the print statement is not printing anything. The problem starts there.

Comment: Try changing it to ```accel = open(os.path.join(file_path, '../imu/accel.txt'))```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `os.path.dirname(__file__)` to `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))`

The problem is that when you run your script as `python imu_pub2.py` the `__file__` variable is set to "imu_pub2.py".  That string is just a filename with no directory part, so `dirname(__file__)` produces an empty string.  That means that `file_path` is an empty string, which is why nothing shows up when you `print` it.  Since the result of `dirname` is empty, `accel` gets set to just "/../imu/accel.txt" and apparently no such file exists on your machine so the `open` fails.

Using `abspath` will get the full directory path for `__file__`, and that will let `dirname` produce the result you want.

BTW, kra3 is correct when he says to use `os.path.join` instead of just concatenating strings together.  But that's not the cause of the bug.

Comment: Hi. It works now. But I don't understand how it had worked with atom. How do you think  'atom' is executing it?

Comment: `__file__` contains the module name as it was specified on the command line, so I expect that atom is running your script as `python /full/path/to/your/imu_pub2.py`.  You could check by making your script wait before exiting (add `import sys` and `sys.stdin.readline()`, or `import time` and `time.sleep(200)`). Then use `ps` in another terminal window, or `taskmgr` if you're on Windows, to see exactly how atom constructed the command line.